# Convert protobuf message to string in Java for persistency

Tags: java, string, encoding, protocol-buffers, base32

I am working on a project which stores all data in key/value pairs. Both the key and value are strings. Changing this is beyond the current scope. Each data concept is represented by a protobuf message.

So, I must store a protobuf message as a string. Is it enough to store the message as message.toByteString().toString()? Or should I encode the byte[], with Base32 encoding for example?

**edit**

Using ByteString for persistency does not seem to work:

```
Message m = ...;
ByteString s = m.toByteString();
ByteString s_ = ByteString.copyFromUtf8(s.toStringUtf8());
Message.PARSER.parseFrom(s_);
```

*While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field.  This could mean either than the input has been truncated or that an embedded message misreported its own length.*

So do you propose to use Base32 encoding on m.toByteArray()? Please note that changing the data type from string to byte[] currently is out of scope.

Thank you!

Comment: I added extra information. See my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must store an encoded message as text, you should use base64 encoding. Base32 also works, but base64 is a bit more compact and better-standardized.

Using `toStringUtf8()` does not work because the encoded message is not UTF-8. This approach will therefore corrupt your data.